# Camera + hardware for sky-watching project

Tags: hardware, camera

I would like to build a Raspberry Pi setup with a camera, the idea being that the camera sits outside, pointed at the sky, and sends the video stream to my computer,  inside my home. I'd like to use the camera for skywatching/recording (stars, meteors, clouds, etc.).
I am a computer scientist, so I know my way around code - it is more the hardware and camera that I am not all that familiar with, as I am pretty new to Raspberry Pi. Also, if you have any general advice, I'd love to hear it.

So, questions:

1. What is the ideal camera for this?
2. Which PI would be best here?
3. Which (if any) other modules/boards (e.g. wifi module) do I need?
4. How can I power this thing? What are my options? Ideally, I would not have to recharge batteries, and I would not need to run a power cord outside...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. You have two options here: the [Camera Module V2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/) or the [HQ Module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-high-quality-camera/). The HQ Module is much newer and can shoot at the highest resolution, but you will also need to buy your own lens for it.
2. Any Pi would do fine for your use case. If you would want to stream at higher resolutions or run some kind of inference on the Pi, you should go for the Pi 4.
3. No module/boards would be required with the Pi 3 and 4, just a power supply and a network connection.
4. For the Power Supply, you could use a rechargeable lithium-ion battery. For example, you would use a 5v 3a lithium battery for a Pi 4. Read the individual Power requirements [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md).

These questions and the project seems extremely simple on the hardware side if you're using a Pi. Getting started with the Raspberry Pi is pretty simple. Just watch a few videos, and you'll be able to get through your project with no trouble.